# Export database to custom file format

Tags: sql-server, database, database-schema

I would like write a command line tool which exports dumps from database data in a text file with a custom format defined by me (not `CSV`, `SQL` or any widely used file format). The schema is quite complex and the output file will be in a well-defined [NACHA](https://secureinstantpayments.com/sip/help/interface_specs/external/NACHA_format.pdf) file format. I am going to use C# with .NET Core for this task, as it is the required technology by the client.

But I was wondering if there is such a tool or language where you can map tables, columns, rows to text elements as rows, paragraphs, etc. ?

Thank you!

Comment: You are looking only for the data? Or you need the objects definitions, too.

Comment: I need only the data to be exported, but instead of writing selects and joins or use ORM and then writing in file, I was wondering whether there is a tool or language in which the output format can be defined.

Answer (score 0):

There are various build-in `SQL Server Management Studio` export/import tools. I guess for your needs, it will be best to build your functionality over the [BCP Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) as it has various options which can be populated using your tool.

You may need to write additional query to get tables in the particular database and then export their data one by one using the BCP utility. Then, you can merge the files or zip them.